# A configurable (high/low level) programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a programming language that can be both high and low level? I'll elaborate...

Say, for example, you want to write an enterprise system which needs good abstractions and static typing (among other things), so you pick Java. But then, you need a portion of this system to be very low latency, so you pick C++ and do your garbage collection. Then, you want some kind of automated build script, so you quickly write something up in python.

Is there a language that could do all of these tasks, and be configurable such that one can use a GC or not if specified, the script be interpreted or not if specified, and the language can have static typing if specified? - Say, a unified syntax with optional static typing, customizable GC, and compilers..a sort of customizable Frankenstein language?

Disclaimer, I have not taken any programming language/compiler course, so this may be a noob-ish question!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really a site for answering generic questions like this that are highly opinion based. It is more for questions solving a specific software challenge one is having. Discuss questions of this nature on sites more designed for open discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real world challenges are better dealt with multiple programming languages and programming language implementations.

Since you mentioned Python, important parts of the library are implemented in C (or in Cython) for performance reasons.

The programming languages involved on a modern Web site are at least HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, plus a templating language, plush the language used for the backend, plus the language used for services, plus SQL or the likes for querying databases.

The history of programming has recurring attempts at a single programming language for everything (ADA comes to mind), and each of them resulted in either inconsistent languages or complicated code. All of them were short-sighted.

Comment: Well, Ada is still strong for what it came up! Also, you can use it for everything.